# "How To Make a Tile-Based Game with Cocos2D 2.X" Make this tutorial with cocos2d V3

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, game-engine, tile

I have a small problem. In this tutorial [How To Make a Tile-Based Game with Cocos2D 2.X](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29458/how-to-make-a-tile-based-game-with-cocos2d-2-x) used cocos2d V2.0, I wanna make this in cocos2d V3.0. So, it doesn't work! Thanks! (I don't speak english)

I think problem in this line - self.position = viewPoint;

```
@property (strong) CCTiledMap *tileMap;
@property (strong) CCTiledMapLayer *background;
@property (strong) CCSprite *player;



- (id)init
{
    // Apple recommend assigning self with supers return value
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return(nil);

    // Enable touch handling on scene node
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    self.tileMap = [CCTiledMap tiledMapWithFile:@"TileMap.tmx"];
    self.background = [_tileMap layerNamed:@"Background"];
    [self addChild:_tileMap z:-1];

    CCTiledMapObjectGroup *objectGroup = [_tileMap objectGroupNamed:@"Objects"];
    NSAssert(objectGroup != nil, @"tile map has no objects object layer");

    NSDictionary *spawnPoint = [objectGroup objectNamed:@"SpawnPoint"];
    int x = [spawnPoint[@"x"] integerValue];
    int y = [spawnPoint[@"y"] integerValue];

    _player = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"Player.png"];
    _player.position = ccp(x,y);

    [self addChild:_player];
    [self setViewPointCenter:_player.position];

    // done
    return self;
}


- (void)setViewPointCenter:(CGPoint) position {

    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].viewSize;

    int x = MAX(position.x, winSize.width/2);
    int y = MAX(position.y, winSize.height/2);
    x = MIN(x, (_tileMap.mapSize.width * _tileMap.tileSize.width) - winSize.width / 2);
    y = MIN(y, (_tileMap.mapSize.height * _tileMap.tileSize.height) - winSize.height/2);
    CGPoint actualPosition = ccp(x, y);

    CGPoint centerOfView = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
    CGPoint viewPoint = ccpSub(centerOfView, actualPosition);

    self.position = viewPoint;
}

-(void)touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchLocation];
    touchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:touchLocation];

    CGPoint playerPos = _player.position;
    CGPoint diff = ccpSub(touchLocation, playerPos);

    if ( abs(diff.x) > abs(diff.y) ) {
        if (diff.x > 0) {
            playerPos.x += _tileMap.tileSize.width;
        } else {
            playerPos.x -= _tileMap.tileSize.width;
        }
    } else {
        if (diff.y > 0) {
            playerPos.y += _tileMap.tileSize.height;
        } else {
            playerPos.y -= _tileMap.tileSize.height;
        }
    }

    CCLOG(@"playerPos %@",CGPointCreateDictionaryRepresentation(playerPos));

    // safety check on the bounds of the map
    if (playerPos.x <= (_tileMap.mapSize.width * _tileMap.tileSize.width) &&
        playerPos.y <= (_tileMap.mapSize.height * _tileMap.tileSize.height) &&
        playerPos.y >= 0 &&
        playerPos.x >= 0 )
    {
        [self setPlayerPosition:playerPos];
    }

    [self setViewPointCenter:_player.position];
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(touchLocation));
}

-(void)setPlayerPosition:(CGPoint)position {
    _player.position = position;
}
```

Comment: Man, that is *-touchesBegan:withEvent:*.

Comment: Can you make this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29458/how-to-make-a-tile-based-game-with-cocos2d-2-x) in cocos2d V3?

Comment: Sorry. I am not familiar with Cocos2D. May be someone else could help you. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time! (Google Translate)

Comment: Maybe you should do it with v2.0 first, learn how cocos2d works, then you'll find it a lot easier to do the same thing again but in v3.0

Comment: LearnCocos2D You're right ... ... I wanted to save time ... Thank you, and hello from Abkhazia :)

Comment: @EmptyStack According to the [Cocos2d V3 documentation](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/3.0-rc1/Classes/CCResponder.html#//api/name/touchBegan:withEvent:), *-touchBegan:withEvent:* is correct.

Comment: Alright. Its my mistake. I didn't know that method exists in Cocos2d. Please ignore that comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the area of the user interaction is by default bound to the `contentSize` of the scene (screen size).

When calling your `setViewPointCenter` method, you are moving the scene position out of this area where the touch event is not handled.

You have to extend this area of the `contentSize` of the tile map like that :

```
[self setContentSize:[_tileMap contentSize]];
self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```