# Tile map tutorial for cocos2d 3.x?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I wanted to follow a tile map game tutorial for Cocos2D:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/29458/how-to-make-a-tile-based-game-with-cocos2d-2-x

However, it seems I can't follow this with Cocos2D 3.0 as the new Cocos2D doesn't seem to even include `CCTMXLayer` and `CCTMXTiledMap`.

I suppose I could install an older version of Cocos2D, but that could open a whole new can of worms. Is there some up to date tutorial or system for tile map games?

Thanks

Comment: hi..did you get working v3 tileMap sample ? please check this and answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52019991/cocos2dx-3-17-tilemap-basic-sample-wrong-tilecord-position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a similar question with up to date version of Cocos2D objects:
["How To Make a Tile-Based Game with Cocos2D 2.X" Make this tutorial with cocos2d V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21377795/how-to-make-a-tile-based-game-with-cocos2d-2-x-make-this-tutorial-with-cocos2d)

Answer (score 0):

for example:
HelloWorldScene.h

```
cpp
// Inside the HelloWorld class declaration
cocos2d::Sprite *_player;
```

HelloWorldScene.cpp

```
cpp
// Inside the init method, after setting "_background =" 
TMXObjectGroup *objects = _tileMap->getObjectGroup("Objects");
CCASSERT(NULL != objects, "'Objects' object group not found");
auto spawnPoint = objects->getObject("SpawnPoint");
CCASSERT(!spawnPoint.empty(), "SpawnPoint object not found");
int x = spawnPoint["x"].asInt();
int y = spawnPoint["y"].asInt();
_player = Sprite::create("Player.png");
_player->setPosition(x, y);
addChild(_player);
setViewPointCenter(_player->getPosition());
```